# Focused text box is moves, when we scroll form panel created in sencha+phonegap in android device

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

Here is my code.

Focusable text box is self moves, when we scroll form panel created in sencha+phonegap in android device

please suggest solution 
thanks

Ext.define('mobileapp.view.Demographics', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
        xtype: 'Demographics',
        requires: [
        'Ext.field.Number',
        'Ext.field.Email',

```
    ],
    config: {
        items:[
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name : 'firstname',
            label: 'First Name',
            maxLength : 50,
            required: true,
            labelWrap :true,
            placeHolder: 'First Name (required)'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name : 'lastname',
            label: 'Last Name',
            maxLength : 50,
            required: true,
            labelWrap :true,
            placeHolder: 'Last Name (required)'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            name : 'age',
            label: 'Age',
            labelWrap :true,
            maxLength : 3,
            placeHolder: 'Age (In Years)',
            listeners: [
                {
                    event: 'blur',
                    fn: function(a) {
                        if(a.getValue()!=null)
                        {
                            var TodayDate= new Date;
                            var CurrentYear= TodayDate.getFullYear();
                            var date=new Date;
                            date.setDate(01);
                            date.setMonth(0);
                            date.setFullYear(CurrentYear-(parseInt(a.getValue())));
                            Ext.getCmp('DatePickerField').setValue(date);
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
},
});
```